# How to connect to posgres in Heroku from Python?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have followed the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres#connecting-in-python) and in my Python code I've added:

```
import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['postgres://sficoXXX:842YYY@ec2-54-165-184-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/database-name']

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```

The URL I took from the session Config Vars (I used: `heroku pg:credentials:url`).

When I check the connection to the database using `heroku pg:psql` everything seems to be working fine.

But after deploying it shows the following error:

> Failed to create session:
> 'postgres://sficoXXX:842YYY@ec2-54-165-184-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/database-name'
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/spoleto/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/otree/session.py",
> line 447, in create_session_traceback_wrapper
> return create_session(**kwargs)   File "/Users/spoleto/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/otree/session.py",
> line 418, in create_session
> func(subsession)   File "/Users/spoleto/PycharmProjects/upstream-reciprocity/prototypes/Consent/**init**.py",
> line 35, in creating_session
> DATABASE_URL = os.environ[postgres://sficoXXX:842YYY@ec2-54-165-184-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/database-name']
> File "/Users/spoleto/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/os.py", line
> 675, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError(key) from None

Am I doing this right? Where does the error come from? How is the connection supposed to be established?

This is almost a copy/paste from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of putting a connection string into an environment variable is so it doesn't need to be in your source code.

Instead of looking up the value of `DATABASE_URL` manually and pasting it into your source code, use the *name* of the environment variable:

```py
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

Now your *code* will look for an environment variable with that name dynamically every time it runs, and set your `DATABASE_URL` variable to the value of the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

(The code you show in your question looks for an environment variable named `postgres://...`, which is very unlikely to exist.)

Note that this will fail with an `IndexError` if an environment variable named `DATABASE_URL` cannot be found. A safer way of doing this might be to use the `.get()` method (make sure to use round parentheses instead of square brackets):

```py
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
```

Now you can even provide a fallback, e.g. for local development:

```py
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
```

---

Note: You didn't leak your whole connection string in your question, but I suggest you [rotate your credentials](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-credentials-rotate-database) anyway:

```
heroku pg:credentials:rotate
```

This will invalidate the old connection string and generate a new one.

The good news is that your `DATABASE_URL` environment variable will automatically be updated, and since your code now reads that value at runtime, it will continue to work!